# predicate checking for UUID not working in swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

My attempts to fetch records from coredata based on a matching UUID is crashing the app, I get the correct instance for binding and there is no other error , but the error

```
Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.Binding<Swift.Optional<Foundation.UUID>>' (0x14f02c810) to 'Swift.CVarArg' (0x14f02c8c8).
```

keeps showing up every time I try and fetch the records , can any one kindly suggest where is my issue

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

    struct EditViewData: View {
        
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
        @Binding var carData: CarDetails
        @ObservedObject var dataEdit: DataController
        @FetchRequest var mycarsdata: FetchedResults<CarDetails>
        init(carData: Binding<CarDetails>, dataEdit: DataController) {
            _mycarsdata = FetchRequest(entity: CarDetails.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "carid == %@", carData.carid as! CVarArg ))
            self._carData = carData
            self.dataEdit = dataEdit
        }
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                TextField("Brand", text: .init(
                    get: { self.carData.brandNameTemp  },
                    set: { self.carData.brandName = $0 }
                )) {
                    let carChange = CarDetails(context: moc)
                    for item in mycarsdata {
                        item.brandName = carData.brandNameTemp
                    }
                    dataEdit.save()
                }
               
            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
           
           
        }
    }
```

### Edited Working Code with no insertion with updates

```
   import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct EditViewData: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @ObservedObject var carData: CarDetails
    @ObservedObject var dataEdit: DataController
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Brand", text: .init(
                get: { self.carData.brandNameTemp  },
                set: { self.carData.brandName = $0 }
            )) {
            
               
               
                
                dataEdit.save()
            }
           
        }
      //  .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
       
       
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Binding var carData: CarDetails` for a CoreData object is pointless, All CoreData objects are `ObservableObject`s they should be wrapped using `@ObservedObject`. `Binding` is by definition a two-way connection, there is no way to "2-way-connect" to the persistent container. That. `FetchedResults` isn't needed.

Comment: I really had no knowledge of that , now all errors are gone but my core data is inserting a row along with an update now, I was thinking that by fetching that specific record from coredata , I can over come the issue, earlier I I had not use fetchresult , but my issue was insert along with update, is there a way I can avoid it, I have update the code which cause insertion of records while updating with return in textfield, thanks

Comment: Just use `$carData.yourvariable` once it is wrapped with `@ObservedObject`. Then `moc.save()` to update. If you get the optional binding error because the attribute is optional there are different solutions on SO for that. Apple has made this very simple don't over think. `let carChange = CarDetails(context: moc)` creates a new object, that is unnecessary.

Comment: I want to emphasize since I just saw your update ~`@Binding var carData: CarDetails`~ is **incorrect** use `@ObservedObject var carData: CarDetails`

Comment: thank you so much , this was really amazing 10 minutes of upgrade in my coredata knowledge , now all works well , I will update the working code in question